# What and How RabbitMQ Topic Permissions Works

Tags: rabbitmq

What is "Topic Permissions" and how does it work? is it related to the "Topic" exchange type? why only this type of exchange has permissions? When I search for **Exchanges**, only RabbitMQ **default** is listed:

Below the Exchanges in the combo:

> AMQP default: Type direct
> amq.direct: Type direct 
> amq.fanout: Type fanout
> amq.headers: Type headers
> amq.match: Type headers
> amq.rabbitmq.trace: Type topic
> amq.topic: Type topic

and do not list others that I created.

Configuration image

[image]

Instaled plugins:

```
 E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status: * = running on rabbit@DESKTOP-F8BDSSI
```

`[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.8.12`
`[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.8.12`
`[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.8.12`

Comment: I assume based on the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#topic-authorisation) I found and the fact it doesn't show up in my admin console, that you have either MQTT or STOMP plugin enabled. Extract from the doc: `Topic authorisation targets protocols like STOMP and MQTT, which are structured around topics and use topic exchanges under the hood.`

Comment: @Olivier I edit my question with plugins, obtained with CMD: rabbitmq-plugins.bat list